# Getting onWheel event to work on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, scroll, touch

I have a (React) component which contains many `<div>`s of text mapped from an array. The height of the container is small, and I used Javascript to implement scrolling. Here is the code:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      visibleTop: 0
    };
  }

  scrollHandler(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const { deltaY } = ev;
    const { visibleTop } = this.state;
    const { clientHeight: height } = this.visibleBox;

    if ( visibleTop >= 10 && deltaY < 0 ) {
      return;
    }

    if ( visibleTop <= (300 - height) && deltaY > 0 ) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      visibleTop: prevState.visibleTop - deltaY
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const {
      state: { visibleTop },
      scrollHandler
    } = this;

    return (
      <div className='content-box' onWheel={scrollHandler}>
        <div className='visible-box'
          style={{ top: visibleTop }}
          ref={el => this.visibleBox = el}>
          {
            logs.map((log, index) => (
              <div className='log-line' key={`${log}-${index}`}>{log}</div>
            ))
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The `.visible-box` div is a tall `div`, sort of clipped by the `.content-box`. I think you get my logic.

Now, this works perfect on desktop, but **doesn't work on mobile device**. From what I researched I found that `mousewheel` event does not fire on mobile. I also read about `touchmove` event, but it gives only the (x,y) coordinate of the touch, but not a `deltaY` like `mousewheel`.
How can I implement this on mobile ?

Comment: You will have to go with a whole different computation when it comes to touch events. This is exactly why I try to avoid desktop-only events properties whenever I can. Or I code both the desktop and mobile version together, so I won't be pulling my hair trying to make the other one work later.

Comment: You would have to use the x and y values of the touch events and perhaps get the window scroll properties such as `scrollTop` to go about your alternative computation for mobile. `if(event.type == 'touchmove')` or `if(event.touches)` should work easily as a flag for the mobile version